# Organize text file into smaller text files

Tags: c#, database, sorting

I am working on a program that will take a specifically formatted text file and organize its entries (seperated by lines) into smaller text files. This program will find a keyword (Teacher A, Teacher B, etc.) and assume that line should be placed in a specific file (carpentry.txt, welding.txt, etc.) So far, it seems that it should work, but when its all done, the files are blank. Any help?

```
int x = 0;
string[] carp = { };
string[] weld = { };
string[] elec = { };
string[] hvac = { };

string[] alltext = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");

while(x < alltext.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(alltext[x]);
    x++;
}

while(x < alltext.Length)
{
    if(alltext[x].Contains("Teacher A"))
    {
        carp.Append(carp + "\n" + alltext[x]);
    }
    else if(alltext[x].Contains("Teacher B"))
    {
        weld.Append(weld + "\n" + alltext[x]);
    }
    else if (alltext[x].Contains("Teacher C"))
    {
        elec.Append(elec + "\n" + alltext[x]);
    }
    else if (alltext[x].Contains("Teacher D"))
    {
        hvac.Append(hvac + "\n" + alltext[x]);
    }
    x++;
}

x = 0;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("carp.txt"))
{
    while (x < carp.Length)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(carp[x].ToString());
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
}
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("weld.txt"))
{
    while (x < weld.Length)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(weld[x].ToString());
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
}
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("elec.txt"))
{
    while (x < elec.Length)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(elec[x].ToString());
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
}
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("hvac.txt"))
{
    while (x < hvac.Length)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(hvac[x].ToString());
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
}
```

Once again, when the program finishes, the output in the text files is blank.

Answer (score -1):

Use `File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);` instead of StreamWriter. It's much easier that way.

If you want to use StreamWriter, be sure so flush your changes with, in your case `sw.Flush();`. This should write the text to your file.